# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it(selenium)

Tags: selenium

I have extracted the following code from selenium IDE.(c# remote control)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Selenium;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
[TestFixture]
public class MyFirstVCTest
{
    private ISelenium selenium;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

    [Test]
    public void TheNewTest()
    {
        selenium.Open("/");
    } 

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome","http://demo.volunteercampaigns.com/");
        selenium.Start();
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            selenium.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }

    [Test]
    public void TheMyFirstVCTest()
    {
        selenium.Open("/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1");
        selenium.Click("link=Login");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.Type("id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmailAddress", "elonadminss@eeeorbees.com");
        selenium.Type("id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword", "orbs123");
        selenium.Click("id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnlogin");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.Click("id=ctl00_lblUserName");
        selenium.Click("id=ctl00_lnkSignOut");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }
}
}
```

i created a webform and added a button there.

in button click event i wrote this code

```
SeleniumTests.MyFirstVCTest m = new SeleniumTests.MyFirstVCTest();
    m.SetupTest();
    m.TheMyFirstVCTest();
    m.TeardownTest();
```

i included all .dll files. its running fine(no errors and warnings).

but after clicking button i am getting the following error

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4444
```

what should i do??

thanks in advance..

**Note to viewers**: This post may help you : [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](http://coding-issues.blogspot.com/2012/11/no-connection-could-be-made-because.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"...the target machine actively refused it" means the server could be reached and responded within the timeout, but the specified port wasn't open. This can have several reasons, e.g. a local firewall blocking the connection. Are you sure the server is listening on the right IP/port?

Comment: that port number(4444) i got defaultly from selenium IDE.

Comment: The port doesn't have to be wrong, but it might still be blocked (e.g. some personal firewalls will block all local TCP/IP connections to/from localhost). Have you tried accessing it using some simple tool like ssh or telnet?

Comment: somehow now the error is changed to "Unable to connect to the remote server". wats it?

Comment: This is really hard to guess, but the basic idea behind my answer might still be true. There's something keeping your client code to connect to the server. Are you using any kind of firewall? If you're running something from the MSVC IDE, the actual process name you have to allow might be different (based on your version and the firewall this could be the IDE's main process as well as some "yourexe.vchost.exe" file.

Comment: The thing which is wrong here is, I dint start the selenium server. That's why i am getting the error. After starting the selenium server, the error was gone. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I get the same error, but on a different line of code. Hopefully this might help someone somewhere even if it doesn't answer the initial question.

```
    public override void SetupTest()
    {
        Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        base.SetupTest();
    }
```

I'm using the WebDriver (I don't run the Selenium server), and the constructor of FirefoxDriver throws the Exception.

Sometimes I get this exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

with this call stack:

```
    WebDriver.dll!OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.ExtensionConnection.ConnectToBrowser(System.TimeSpan timeToWait) Line 247    C#
    WebDriver.dll!OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.ExtensionConnection.Start() Line 98  C#
    WebDriver.dll!OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver.StartClient() Line 237  C#
    WebDriver.dll!OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.RemoteWebDriver(OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, OpenQA.Selenium.ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) Line 89    C#
    WebDriver.dll!OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxBinary binary, OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile profile, OpenQA.Selenium.ICapabilities capabilities, System.TimeSpan commandTimeout) Line 172    C#
    WebDriver.dll!OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxBinary binary, OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile profile, System.TimeSpan commandTimeout) Line 167    C#
    WebDriver.dll!OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxBinary binary, OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile profile) Line 154    C#
    WebDriver.dll!OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile profile) Line 132  C#
    SetupTest() Line 513    C#
```

Sometimes I get this exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

with this call stack:

```
    WebDriver.dll!OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.ExtensionConnection.DetermineNextFreePort(string host, int port) Line 161    C#
    WebDriver.dll!OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.ExtensionConnection.Start() Line 88  C#
    [same as above]
```

But one thing I didn't realize at first is that if you continue execution (F5), everything is fine. The Exception must be handled in the WebDriver.

The only thing is that I had the **DEBUG/Exceptions/CLR Exceptions: Thrown [checked]**.
Just uncheck that and everything runs without throwing/breaking. Took me a while to realize that. Leftovers of a previous debugging session...

Comment: Could you please elaborate "just uncheck that"? I am using Python and I am in the same situation so knowing what you did would lead me to find the same thing for Python.

Answer (score 3):

To add more clarity for the readers: Start selenium server using the followings basic steps:

- Download selenium -server standalone from official selenium download
  page.

  - Open command prompt.
  - Navigate to the folder using "Cd ".
  - Add this command: "java - jar ".
  - Hit enter.
  - Selenium server will be started.

Comment: Hi Das. Thank you for your reply. The samething which you said above is explained clearly here : http://coding-issues.blogspot.com/2012/11/no-connection-could-be-made-because.html

Comment: For me, this was the solution. cmd and then java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar

Answer (score 3):

I got this because a part of my code held a reference to a stale driver.

```
var driver1 = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();
driver1.Close();
driver1.Quit();
driver1.Dispose();

var x = driver1.FindElements(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way i do it, the structure of my class.

```
 [TestFixture, Parallelizable(ParallelScope.None)]
 public class UserTest : BaseTestClass
 {
            [SetUp]
            public void SetUp()
            {
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                //options.AddArgument("--headless");
                options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
                var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                WebDriver = WebDriverExtended.InitWebDriver(driver, driver.Url);
                WebDriver.Start();
            }

           [TearDown]
            public void Cleanup()
            {
             //Dispose after every single test, fixed the problem.
                WebDriver.Close();
                WebDriver.Quit();
                WebDriver.Dispose();
            }

      [Test]
      public void LoginTest()
      {
       //My test ...
      }
}
```

I am currently using Selenium.Support v3.6.0 and Selenium.WebDriver v3.6.0.
Disposing the webdriver fixed my problem

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:4444

Comment: `Quit` already calls `Dispose` under the hood. And I still have the problem even doing so.

Comment: Adding `ParallelScope.None` to my `[Parallelizable]` decorator seems to have made the difference. Thank you I've been fighting this issue for days!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this type of error.
What I was doing is I was closing the browser and quitting the driver at end of the test, but I forgot to make `Webdriver wait = null;`
So again when I tried to open a new browser for the next test, it will eventually start the browser and redirects to the URL but at the time of interacting it was giving me this error `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`.

So I found that I was using `wait` of closed driver instance.
So please check whether you are using anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a problem with the scope of the services. The ones that were using WebDriver were registered as singletons, and every subsequent request after the first one was failing. (even though I was closing and recreating the web driver instance manually after each request).  Once I changed the scope to transient it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the remote machine on which scripts are to be run is up and working. Secondly make sure chrome driver and chrome is update on it. Lastly no firewall is blocking ur access to remote machine.

PS: Manually close the selenium server and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was solved by changing settings within Chrome, as follows:

- go into Chrome Menu Settings  (three vertical dots / hamburger menu)
- scroll down to Advanced, and expand it
- System > Open Proxy Settings
- UN-check "Automatically Detect Settings"